# Is it possible to make hibrid atoms?

Tags: particle-physics, atoms, antimatter, matter

Is it possible to make an atom which is half matter and half antimatter (mostly meaning that it's particles are equaled) ? And if it would be possible, how this atom would behave comparably with its normal counterpart?

Comment: Wrong use of word. I wanted to ask is it possible to exist an atom which has both matter and anti matter particles and somehow it is stable

Comment: Mesons are comprised of a quark and an antiquark.

Comment: Does [positronium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positronium) count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Atoms](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Chemical/atom.html) have a specific definition, they are quantum mechanical bound states of a central positive nucleus made up by protons and neutrons, and electrons bound by the electromagnetic interaction  to make a stable entity, called atom. There exist antiatoms, i.e. antiprotons and antineutron tied into a nucleus with positrons bound around them.

You cannot make a stable  atom with mixed particles and antiparticles either in the nucleus or in the orbitals because the particles would [annihilate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilation) with
antiparticles.

As observed in the comments to your question, there exist transient states of bound particles to antiparticles, as the positronium, which is an electron-positron bound electromagnetically, but they decay very fast, the rapidity can be calculated using the appropriate interactions and conservation laws. Charged [pions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pion) , made up by a quark and antiquark last longer, because of conservation laws, whereas the neutral pion's quark antiquark pair annihilate very fast because charge conservation allows it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer!